# Jquery Sortable List with getJSON method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, getjson

I am working on a tutorial that uses getJSON to add list items to the DOM. There also needs to be the JqueryUI sortable plugin to sort the lists. For some reason unknown to me the plugin does not work. What am I missing here? Should the sortable function be inside the getJSON callback? Any suggestions would be great.

here is my code I have so far:

```
$(function () {
 $('body h1').append('My Todo List');

 $.getJSON('todo.json', function(data) {

var html = '<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">';

$.each(data, function(index) {

    var todo = data[index];
    if (todo.done === false) {
        todo.done = (" ")

    } else {
        todo.done = ("(DONE)")
    }
    html += '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' + todo.who + " needs to " + todo.task + " by " + todo.dueDate + " " + todo.done + '</li>';
});
    html += '</ul>';
   $('body #container').append(html);
});



});
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery ToDo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
            $("#sortable").disableSelection("refresh");
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
        #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 14px; height: 18px; }
        #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<div id="container">

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JSON

```
[
{"task":"get milk","who":"Scott","dueDate":"2013-05-19","done":false},
{"task":"get broccoli","who":"Elisabeth","dueDate":"2013-05-21","done":false},
{"task":"get garlic","who":"Trish","dueDate":"2013-05-30","done":false},
{"task":"get eggs","who":"Josh","dueDate":"2013-05-15","done":true}
```

]

Comment: see the updated answer with the working jsbin demo...........

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the `sortable` after appending the data. In your `$.getJSON` callback call the `sortable` again like given below. jquery will wire the `sortable` only if the element is present in the `DOM` when the dom is ready. you are adding the elements dynamically so you have to call the `sortable` again after adding the elements into the `DOM`.

```
 $.getJSON('todo.json', function(data) {

var html = '<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">';

$.each(data, function(index) {

    var todo = data[index];
    if (todo.done === false) {
        todo.done = (" ")

    } else {
        todo.done = ("(DONE)")
    }
    html += '<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' + todo.who + " needs to " + todo.task + " by " + todo.dueDate + " " + todo.done + '</li>';
});
    html += '</ul>';
   $('body #container').append(html);
});

$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

});
```

**Edit**

Here is the bin http://jsbin.com/IPubElE/1/

demo uses the in-memory data but it should work fine even inside the callback method.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that approach but this does not work either.

Comment: i have added the bin to the answer which has the working demo of `sortable` with the data you have given look at that......